# Is there a difference using Python3 in IDLE3 or in Ubuntu 14.04 terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, python-idle

Is there a difference using IDLE3 or the Ubuntu 14.04 terminal for Python3 interpretation? In that case, what are the differences?

Comment: I don't know (I doubt it) but you can find out by importing sys and running `print(sys.version)` in each.

Comment: Right, so if the versions are the same, there is no difference? Thing is, I heard there was, but I can't see what that would be.

Comment: I also can't see what they would be. Maybe someone else knows of some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the Ubuntu terminal, but I will assume that it is a typical terminal program.  If you type `python3`, it starts python3, which prints, in the same window, something like `Python 3.4.3 ...` and then a prompt `>>>`.  You interact with python3 via the terminal program.

If you type `idle3`, it runs a python gui program (Idle) with python3.  That program prints, in a separate window, something like `Python 3.4.3 ...` and then a prompt `>>>`.  You interact with python3 via this python program. In either case, any code you enter is executed by python3. For nearly all code you might enter, such as anything in the tutorial, the printed response will be the same.

The difference in terms of interaction is that in the terminal, if it is typical, you enter and recall (with up arrow?) lines of code, whereas in Idle, you enter and recall (with Alt-p) statements, which may comprise multiple lines. Also, Idle syntax colors your code, whereas your terminal may not.

A bigger difference is that Idle is not just a Python terminal or shell, but is an integrated development environment that includes an editor that works with the shell.  You can run code from the editor with F5.  If there is an error traceback in the shell, you can right click on an error line and go to the line with the error.

Comment: The terminal manages multiple lines as well surely? (Like functions or `if` clauses?) Thanks for tip about recall in Idle, I had wondered about that. _But notice it is `alt p` and not `ctrl-p` like you wrote_.

Comment: Thank for the correction.  Read terminals are line oriented.  Windows Command Prompt is line oriented.  One can only enter, edit, and recall single lines.  If Ubuntu's terminal recognizes that '... ' lines after a '>>> ' line constitute a block of code, good for it.  I don't know.